# Loop Freezing Excel After Printing

Tags: excel, vba, csv, printing, export-to-csv

I have a spreadsheet that creates a CSV file and deposits the CSV file in a folder next to the original file. The spreadsheet seems to work fine. When you have your data entered, you click export, and a CSV file is put in a folder called "Uploads" that is next to the original file.

The issue is when I use the quick print button on my Excel quick access toolbar. When I click the quick print button, everything seems to print fine. However, as soon as I close the file,     (EDIT: ALL Printing seems to be freezing the file. As soon as the file is closed)        Excel then goes into a freeze where it looks like it is trying to run some code? I am a novice in VBA so I am not sure what is happening, all I know is that after my file is closed, Excel freezes up and I have to restart Excel. I do not even have any macros or VBA for an Excel close or Excel open trigger.

Can anyone recreate the issue and give me insight into how my code might be doing this?

```
Private Sub Export_Click()

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False

    Dim MyPath As String
    Dim MyFileName As String
    'The path and file names:
    MyPath = ActiveWorkbook.Path & "\Uploads"
    MyFileName = "" & Range("a2") & "_Upload"

    On Error GoTo Ending

    'Makes sure the path name ends with "\":
    If Not Right(MyPath, 1) = "\" Then MyPath = MyPath & "\"
    'Makes sure the filename ends with ".csv"
    If Not Right(MyFileName, 4) = ".csv" Then MyFileName = MyFileName & ".csv"
    'Copies the sheet to a new workbook:
    Sheets("UploadData").Copy
    'The new workbook becomes Activeworkbook:
    With ActiveWorkbook 'Saves the new workbook to given folder / filename:
        .SaveAs FileName:= _
                MyPath & MyFileName, _
                FileFormat:=xlCSV, _
                CreateBackup:=False 'Closes the file
        .Close False
    End With

    ChDir MyPath
    Workbooks.Open FileName:= _
                   MyPath & "\" & MyFileName & """"

    ActiveWorkbook.Save
    ActiveWorkbook.Close

    GoTo Skip

Ending:
    MsgBox ("ERROR! Please make sure you have a folder named Uploads next to the template file")
    ActiveWorkbook.Close

    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

Skip:
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: I cannot seem to find how to attach my file. Can anyone help me attach my file to help recreate the issue?

Comment: What is the purpose of closing the generated `.csv` file, immediately reopening it, saving it *again* with no changes, then closing it again?

Comment: Also, where is the loop you refer to in your question title?

Comment: The file that this is coming from has 100 rows of formulas in it. HOwever, our system that we upload the CSV to will not allow us to upload zeros. So , we created the formula to give a " "" " blank answer when there was no value. However, when this data was converted to a CSV, although the CSV showed the cells as a blank, the file size was enlarged. By OPening the CSV and resaving it, it somehow caused the file size to shrink, and thus allow our system to open the file. It was almost like the blanks that were converted were still secretly there, if that makes sense.

Comment: There should be no Loops. The loop is the error. When I use the quick print option, excel begins looping when I have VBA open. Maybe i should not use the word "loop" due to its VBA connotations, it is more or less a freeze.

Comment: It looks quick print is not the only issue. Printing from the dialog box just froze excel as well. It looks like anytime I print it is having issues. I am very sorry for the inconvenience.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This actually shouldn't work at all, regardless of what you do before you run it.  First, you ensure that `MyPath` ends with a `\` here...

> ```
> 'Makes sure the path name ends with "\":
> If Not Right(MyPath, 1) = "\" Then MyPath = MyPath & "\"
> ```

...but then when you (re)build the same path below you're inserting a second `\`:

> ```
> Workbooks.Open FileName:= _
>                MyPath & "\" & MyFileName & """"
> ```

This *should* always fail. You can avoid this entire problem with paths by using the `Scripting.FileSystemObject`'s `.BuildPath` function:

```
'Requires a reference to Microsoft Scripting Runtime.
Dim filePath As String, fso As New Scripting.FileSystemObject
filePath = fso.BuildPath(ThisWorkbook.Path, MyFileName)
```

You can also use this for the file extension:

```
If LCase$(fso.GetExtensionName(MyFileName)) <> "csv" Then
    MyFileName = MyFileName & ".csv"
End If
```

Note that this test will never be true...

> ```
> If Not Right(MyFileName, 4) = ".csv" Then MyFileName = MyFileName & ".csv"
> ```

...because `MyFileName` will ***always*** end with "load":

> ```
> MyFileName = "" & Range("a2") & "_Upload"
> ```

Also, you should remove all the references to `ActiveWorkbook`.  I have no idea why printing would effect this, but there isn't anything else I can identify that should be an issue. I'd structure it more like this (error handler removed for clarity - don't put it back until you're finished debugging it):

```
'Add a reference to Microsoft Scripting Runtime.
Private Sub Export_Click()
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False

    With New Scripting.FileSystemObject
        Dim filePath As String
        Dim targetDir As String
        targetDir = .BuildPath(ThisWorkbook.Path, "Uploads")
        If Not .FolderExists(targetDir) Then
            MsgBox ("ERROR! Please make sure you have a folder named Uploads next to the template file")
            Exit Sub
        End If
        filePath = .BuildPath(targetDir, ActiveSheet.Range("A2").Value & "_Upload.csv")
    End With
    'Copies the sheet to a new workbook:
    Dim csv As Workbook
    Set csv = Application.Workbooks.Add
    With csv
        ThisWorkbook.Sheets("UploadData").Copy .Sheets(1)
        .SaveAs Filename:=filePath, _
                FileFormat:=xlCSV, _
                CreateBackup:=False 'Closes the file
        .Close xlDoNotSaveChanges
    End With

    'Reopen and re-save to fix formatting.
    Set csv = Workbooks.Open(filePath)
    csv.Close xlSaveChanges

    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: Wow, thank you so much. I will put this into my code immediately and let you know what happens. Sorry about the code, I had copied it from another post on this site to fit my uses. I didnt even know there were so many issues with it. Thank you for all the help.

Comment: I am getting the error "Compiel Error: User defined type not identified"  with the         `With New Scripting.FileSystemObject`   Is there a variable i need to define or somelthing?

Comment: @ZachHenry - Yep.  You need to add a reference.  Go to Tools->References, scroll down to "Microsoft Scripting Runtime" and check the box.

Comment: Wow, this worked. No more errors while freezing up. I had my collegue try it on his computer as well and his froze with the old code so it was definately something in my code. Thank you so much for the help. For a novice like myself, it is awesome to learn from you guys and get help here. THANKS!